# How to show user status(online/offline) in quickblox chat application

Tags: node.js, angular, quickblox

We integrate the Quickblox chat application in our project. We are using Node Js in backend and Angular 7 in frontend. We are already implemented both private and group chat.

Now there is a problem when we are going to show the opponent user status. It is Online or Offline.

It is not clearly mentioned in Quickblox documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Managing presence status is covered in [this](https://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Roster_callbacks) section of QuickBlox documentation.

To receive user status (online / offline), use the following callback:

```
/*
Returns:
  *  (Integer) userId - The sender ID
  *  (String) type - If user leave the chat, type will be 'unavailable'
*/

QB.chat.onContactListListener = function(userId, type) {
  // callback function
};
```